# Google sheets - Subtraction giving unexpected results

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following sheet:

[image: spreadsheet cells]

Why does the difference of two cells with the same value (`J7` & `J8`) not equal zero?

[Here is an example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18Ar0zyrP1uZTjljIrgh0lnSCInxQ7J2Z2piveW5pjSw/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Interesting problem, would be be able to share the sheet for a chance for an answer that's more than just guessing? Until then, my guess would be that the precision as formatted (2 significant digits after the dot) is not the real precision of these numbers, but I haven't been able to replicate such an error.

Comment: Posted an example sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching to Format/Number/Scientific on that cell, you can see the leftover value:

[image: scientific format]

These rounding errors are clearly a regular thing.  You can use a formula such as `=E3-round(E3,2)` to see them for any cell:

[image: rounding remainders]

Clearly, allowing for a small value in the conditional formatting would avoid the problem:

[image: conditional formatting formula]

Comment: Figured it was floating point errors. Thanks for the tips on dealing with it.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @df778899's answer, this is not just a "regular thing". It is an unavoidable consequence of floating-point arithmetics.

The surprising thing is that Google apparently represents numbers internally in the floating-point format. For the same numbers, Excel gives the correct result in the equality comparison, which suggests that unlike Google, Excel's representation is fixed-point.

- EDIT: upon double-checking, one can find examples of floating point errors in Excel too, so this paragraph is not correct.

Students in computer science are taught to always use approximated and not exact comparison for FP numbers. I think it's unreasonable to expect this from spreadsheets users, though.

In practical terms, when comparing fractionals to other fractionals, avoid using

```
=if(j7=j8, ...)
```

or EQ(). Instead, use

```
=if(abs(J7-J8)<0.0001, ...)
```

(with appropriate arbitrary precision)